# Significance of proportions in clustered data

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, cluster-sample

I have data for multiple homes, each of which spends a certain amount of time in Condition 1 and then a certain amount of time in Condition 2.  While in these two conditions, there are  a variable number of observations that can be classified as either type A or type B.  So, for instance, in Condition 1, a home may have 17 type A and 63 type B observations and in condition 2 the home may have 4 type A and 58 type B observations. (It is common for there to be more observations in Condition 1 than Condition 2).  I'm looking to determine if there is a change in the ratio of type A to type B observations based on condition.  For a single home, I think I can use a chi-squared test but I'm not sure how to extend this analysis to multiple homes.  Could I just add all of the observations in Condition 1 and 2 together over homes?  This does not seem correct to me since a single home with large number of observations but little change would bias my results. I should add that the duration and boundaries of Condition 1 and Condition 2 vary over homes. Also, the observations are ordered temporally, but I have not taken this into account yet.  Thanks for any ideas.